# Perl search for specific subdirectory then process

Tags: perl, subdirectory

So for the program I am writing, what I would like for it to do is search through all of the subdirectories within a directory.  If the subdirectory name contains a word, let's say "foo", then the program will open this subdirectory and perform a function on the files within the subdirectory.  Can anybody give me some help on how to go about this?  it also needs to be recursive.  Thanks in advance

Comment: File::Find will do the recursive search you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Find) module, but I believe [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/module/Path::Class) is superior even though it isn't a core module and will likely need installing.

This program finds the files wanted and calls `process` to process them. At present the `process` subroutine simply prints the name of the file for testing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class;

my $dir = dir '/path/to/root/directory';

$dir->recurse(callback => sub {
  my $node = shift;
  return if $node->is_dir;
  my $parent = $node->parent;
  if ($parent->basename =~ /foo/) {
    process($node);
  }
});

sub process {
  my $file = shift;
  print $file, "\n";
}
```

---

**Update**

If you prefer, this program performs the same task using `File::Find`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;
use File::Basename qw/ basename /;

my $dir = '/path/to/root/directory';

find(sub {
  return unless -f;
  if (basename($File::Find::dir) =~ /foo/) {
    process($File::Find::name);
  }
}, $dir);

sub process {
  my $file = shift;
  print $file, "\n";
}
```

---

**Update**

As requested, here is a further solution using [`Path::Class::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/module/Path::Class::Rule) for comparison. As [daxim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46395) suggested the code is a little shorter.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class::Rule;

my $rule = Path::Class::Rule->new;
$rule->file->and(sub { $_->parent->basename =~ /foo/ });

my $next = $rule->iter('/path/to/root/directory');
while ( my $file = $next->() ) {
  process($file);
}

sub process {
  my $file = shift;
  print $file, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you please also add a Path::Class::Rule solution as contrast? Code should be shorter and more declarative.

Comment: Okay how would I do this if I can't install any modules?